# Ways for characterizing stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes

I was wondering what are some general approaches to characterize a stochastic process? Sorry for the vagueness that my questions may have, but let me try to make clear as much as I could that question I have been having for a long time.

1. First of all, I want to understand how detailed a description of a
   stochatic process needs to be so that it can be said to be a
   characterization? The law on the trajectory space, or the mapping
   from the probability space to the trajectory space, or ...? It is
   similar to the case that a random variable cannot be identified
   with its law.
2. It is often mentioned that there are two points-of-view that we are
   taking of a stochastic process, namely (i) a collection of random
   variables, and (ii) a random function of the index (called a
   trajectory).

   In the second approach, I was wondering what is the general approach
   to characterize a stochastic process based on the trajectories? We
   can study the law of a stochastic process on its trajectory space.
   But the process may have some properties on the sample paths, such as continuity, which
   cannot be captured by its law.

   In the first approach, I am not sure what it really is. The examples
   that I have seen is just to study the 1-dimensional distributions,
   such as their moments. Or maybe all the finite dimensional
   distributions are studied in this approach? Also they don't seem
   able to fully characterize a stochastic process.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: 1. Finite dimensional distribution *do* fully characterize a stochastic processes (thanks to KET).
$\phantom{x}\\$
2. *But the process may have some properties on the sample paths, which cannot be captured by its law.* For example?

Comment: Thanks, @Ilya! Can continuity of its trajectories be captured by its law?

Comment: Depends on your definition of the law (which in particular includes the definition of a sample space).

Comment: @Ilya: Do you mean the same as restricting the trajectory space to its subset with the required properties? how detailed a description of a stochatic process needs to be so that it can be said to be a characterization? The law on the trajectory space, or the mapping from the probability space to the trajectory space, or ...? It is similar to the case that a random variable cannot be identified with its law.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by saying that a random variable cannot be identified with its law?

Comment: There can be different r.v.s defined on the same probability space and with the same law. Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7142/discussion-between-ilya-and-tim)